# IF statement in Propel select criteria

Tags: php, sql, mysql, symfony1, propel

I am trying to incorporate an IF statement into my propel criteria.
This is the how I build up my criteria:

```
$c = is_object($c) ? $c : new Criteria();
$c->addSelectColumn("CONCAT(DAYOFYEAR(" . SomePeer::CREATED_AT . "), ' ', YEAR(" . SomePeer::CREATED_AT . ")) AS period");
$c->addSelectColumn("COUNT(" . SomePeer::ID . ") AS registrations");
$c->addSelectColumn("COUNT(IF(" . SomePeer::JOIN . " > 0 AND " . SomePeer::JOIN . " < 3, 1, NULL)) AS coreg");
$c->addJoin(SomePeer::IDENTIFIER, self::TRACKING_IDENTIFIER);
$c->add(SomePeer::ASSOCIATE_ID, $user->getId());
$c->addJoin(self::USER_ID, SomePeer::ID);
$c->addJoin(SomePeer::ID, SomePeer::USER_ID);
$c->add(SomePeer::CREDENTIAL, 'student');
$c->addJoin(SomePeer::PROFILE_ID, SomePeer::ID);
```

However when inspecting the resulting SQL I get the following:

```
SELECT CONCAT(MONTHNAME(some_table.CREATED_AT), ' ', YEAR(some_table.CREATED_AT)) AS period, COUNT(some_table.ID) AS registrations, COUNT(IF(some_table.JOIN > 0 AND some_table.JOIN < 3, 1, NULL)) AS coreg 
FROM `some_table`, `>` `0` `AND` `some_table`, `some_table`, `some_table`, `some_table`, `some_table` 
WHERE some_table.ASSOCIATE_ID=:p1 
AND some_table.CREDENTIAL=:p2 
AND some_table.IDENTIFIER=some_table.TRACKING_IDENTIFIER 
AND some_table.STUDENT_USER_ID=some_table.ID 
AND some_table.ID=some_table.USER_ID 
AND some_table.PROFILE_ID=some_table.ID 
# Params: some_table.ASSOCIATE_ID => 6, some_table.CREDENTIAL => 'credential'"
```

Basically, as you can see, the FROM part of the query is all wrong. I guess propel mistook part of the IF statement in the COUNT as table names and included them in the FROM part of the query.
Has anyone got any ideas how I could get 'round this problem or has someone even been able to get something to work?

Thanks for all your help,

Vincent

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the problem is with the name JOIN. Are you using "join" as a field name??? Try a different name there.

Comment: Sorry field name is JOIN_XYZ removed the latter part to shorten the code without thinking of reserved names.

Comment: Not sure but try this:
$c->addSelectColumn("COUNT(" . SomePeer::ID . ") AS registrations"); 
$c->addSelectColumn(SomePeer::ID); 

$c->addSelectColumn("COUNT(IF(" . SomePeer::JOIN_XYZ . " > 0 AND " . SomePeer::JOIN_XYZ . " < 3, 1, NULL)) AS coreg"); 
$c->addSelectColumn(SomePeer::JOIN_XYZ);

Comment: Last shot - try switching to this syntax:
$c->addAsColumn("registrations", "COUNT(".SomePeer::ID.")");